# What is the maximum number of directed triangles contained in an oriented complete graph?

Tags: graph-theory, triangles, directed-graphs, extremal-graph-theory

Assume there are $n$ vertices, every pair of vertices is connected by an arrow. Then how many directed triangles (for example{ $(1,2),(2,3),(3,1)$})does a graph of this type contain at most?

Comment: Does this graph contain arrows in both directions for every pair of vertices? Or exactly one arrow for every pair of vertices?

Comment: @GregMartin Just one arrow for every pair of vertices

Comment: To be complete it should be both directions.

Comment: @PaulChilds Sorry, I do not what is the technical word for this.

Comment: If it is only one direction then it will depend on your choice of direction. E.g. 12 23 31 has 1 directed triangle but 12 23 13 has none.

Comment: But then I guess the "at most" could make it test over all direction permutations....

Comment: Since adding edges never *eliminates* triangles, we can omit the requirement that every pair of vertices has a single directed edge without loss of generality (as to maximizing the number of triangles for fixed number of vertices).  That said, we can impose such a condition by saying the underlying *undirected* graph is complete.

Comment: Perhaps you should add some context to your Question.  For example, where did you find this problem?  What are the maximum triangle counts for smallish numbers of vertices $n=3,4,5$?

Comment: @hardmath I think this problem is very interesting, but unfortunately I lack the related knowledge to solve it.

Comment: One construction: partition the $n$ vertices as equally as possible, and put directed edges from all vertices in set1 to all vertices in set2 to all vertices in set3; within each set, continue the construction recursively until each set has at most 2 vertices. The resulting sequence is not in OEIS....

Comment: @tmpbin:  Finding the problem very interesting is understandable, and perhaps you could merely add a sentences or paragraph to the body of your Question expressing this interest. (I am an upvoter.) In any case some information about your background would help Readers to supply an Answer at a suitable level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This kind of digraph is called a tournament.  (The idea is a round-robin tournament, with an edge directed from the winner of a game to the loser.)  So, you are asking for the maximum number of (directed) $3$-cycles in a tournament.

This problem was solved in "On the Method of Paired Comparisons," by M.G. Kendall and B. Babington Smith, *Biometrika*, Vol. 31, No. 3/4 (Mar., 1940), pp. 324-345.  The answer is $$\cases{\frac{n^3-n}{24},&$n$ odd\\\frac{n^3-4n}{24},&$n$ even}$$

The paper is available on [JSTOR](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2332613?read-now=1&refreqid=excelsior%3A48d776720729ea9b3a10106a9cc219db&seq=4#page_scan_tab_contents)

Answer (score 2):

Call triangles that are not directed triangles *transitive* ones. A transitive triangle with arcs $(a,b)$, $(a,c)$, $(b,c)$ is said to start at $a$ and end at $c$.

For a vertex $v$ with out-degree $k$, there are $\binom k2$ transitive triangles starting at $v$ (formed by $v$ and any two vertices with an arc from $v$) and $\binom{n-k-1}{2}$ transitive triangles ending at $v$ (formed by $v$ and any two triangles with an arc to $v$). The sum $\binom k2 + \binom{n-k-1}{2}$ is minimized when $k = \lfloor \frac{n-1}{2}\rfloor$ or $k = \lceil \frac{n-1}{2} \rceil$.

If we add up this number over all vertices, we get a number that's at least 
$$
    n \binom{\lfloor \frac{n-1}{2}\rfloor}{2} + n \binom{\lceil \frac{n-1}{2} \rceil}{2}
$$
and this counts each transitive triangle twice: once for the vertex where it starts, and once for the vertex where it ends. So the total number of transitive triangles is at least half of the value above. This is achieved precisely when every out-degree is either $\lfloor \frac{n-1}{2}\rfloor$ or $\lceil \frac{n-1}{2} \rceil$, and this is not hard to do for any value of $n$.

This tells us the minimum number of transitive triangles, and so the maximum number of directed triangles is just however many are left: it is at most
$$
   \binom n3 - \frac12\left(n \binom{\lfloor \frac{n-1}{2}\rfloor}{2} + n \binom{\lceil \frac{n-1}{2} \rceil}{2}\right)
$$
which is roughly $\frac14 \binom n3$.